# What is the different between Handler, Runnable, and Threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

What is the difference between Handler, Runnable, and Threads?

While I was working with android, and I need something to run in the background. I use Threads to run it. Usually I would write a class that extends Thread and implement the run method.

I have also saw some examples that implments runnable and pass into runnable into Threads.

However I am still confused. Can someone give me a clear explanation?

1. What is the point of Runnable if one can write the background code in the Thread's run method?
2. How is Handler used inside thread and why do we need to use it.
3. Android has another thing call runOnUiThread, How do we use that? I know that it is used for updating the UI.

Comment: I dont know much about the Handler and UniThread, hence the comment not answer, but typically you would only ever make Runnable implementations. You would usually only extend thread if you wanted to change something about the impelmentation

Comment: I can't say much about the Android specifics, but you use `Runnable` because it gives you a lot more flexibility in how you schedule the job being run. Using `Thread` directly means you're stuck using one specific strategy.

Comment: It would be great if you can show me some examples.

Answer (score 26):

**Why use Runnable over Thread?**

- `Runnable` separates code that needs to run asynchronously, from **how** the code is run. This keeps your code flexible.  For instance, asynchronous code in a runnable can run on a threadpool, or a dedicated thread.

  A `Thread` has state your runnable probably doesn't need access to. Having access to more state than necessary is poor design.

  Threads occupy a lot of memory.  Creating a new thread for every small actions takes processing time to allocate and deallocate this memory.

**What is runOnUiThread actually doing?**

- Android's [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) queues a `Runnable` to execute on the UI thread.  This is important because you should never update UI from multiple threads.  `runOnUiThread` uses a `Handler`.

  Be aware if the UI thread's queue is full, or the items needing execution are lengthy, it may be some time before your queued `Runnable` actually runs.

**What is a Handler?**

- A handler allows you to post runnables to execute on a specific thread.  Behind the scenes, runOnUi Thread queues your `Runnable` up with Android's Ui Handler so your runnable can execute safely on the UI thread.

Answer (score 11):

**1. Why runnable ?**

Runnable is just an interface you need to instantiate a thread to contain it. Whereas thread already contains the ability to spawn a thread.If you extend Thread you can't extend anything else (Java doesn't support multiple inheritance). You can have multiple interfaces on a class, therefore you could have Runnable.

Also, When you extends Thread class, each of your thread creates unique object and associate with it. When you implements Runnable, it shares the same object to multiple threads.

**2. Why to Use handler and what is it ?**

Handler is written in Java (internally use a Thread), so everything you can do with Handler, you can achieve using a Thread too.

So why should you use Handler? Reason is as below

- Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
  associated with a thread's MessageQueue. To put it in simple terms,
  handler makes your job easy.
- Android has two main rules for handling threads:
- Do not block the UI thread
- Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

To bind by the 2 rules stated above, In android we have 3 built-in methods that can handle the situation when one of your Activity classes are run on or called from a different thread.

We can then schedule the UI updates to be run on the UI thread with these three methods below. The Activity or View then works as a handler (more on handlers below) and schedules your runnable to the UI thread:

1. Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)

   1. View.post(Runnable)
   2. View.postDelayed(Runnable, long) //(long = time to scheduling)

**3. What is UI Thread ?**

UI thread is the main thread in which the UI elements like View and Activity are rendered. Any time consuming operations should not happen in the UI Thread. The application default runs in UI Thread. You need not do anything special to use the UI Thread.

Answer (score 4):

Handler, Runnable, and Threads actually work together, I dont think you should compare them.

> Handler

allows send messages between two threads in a safe manner, that means that sending thread puts message into destination thread queue, and this destination queue will process this message in its appropriate time.

> Runnable

this is an interface that you implement, in implementation you put logic you want to execute on some thread. You can actually use Runnable also in non thread related places. Lots of Java apis actually use Runnable, not only Thread's. You can post Runnable using handler, or you can use it with executors. Runnables are nice because you can implement them in a form of anonymous implementation.

> UniThread

you meant UI Thread? Most user interfaces implements its workings in single thread, all UI elements: windows/widgets communicate using messages (just like in Handler). Ie. user presses button, this initiates a message with information that button was pressed, it is send to UI thread and finally delivered to your listener.

In Android it is forbidden (results in exception) to modify UI elements from non UI thread, this makes sense - if you would modify it from other thread this could happen while UI thread is doing some changes to the same widget - resulting in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I see the Thread class implements Runnable interface. My understanding that runnable has not thing to do with concurrency. Thread is one that does the job. Runnable is just something that one can put on the code so it can be run using a thread. I am correct?

Comment: correct, but Thread is quite low level concept in android, because of quite complicated lifecycles of android components (ie. activities), you should use AsyncTask, Loaders, IntentService-s,...

Comment: Also threads occupy a lot of memory.  They are expensive to create and collect.

Answer (score 1):

Runnable Interface is parent of Thread Class and run() is method of Runnable Interface 
So normally we should prefer Runnable interface over extending thread class because  we don't want to change behavior of the class and we can also  extend another class .It also help in achieving loose coupling as well as we have a benefit of changing the User Interface from any other class.

We Can  change Ui in 4 ways

1.By using Handler example

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
private Handler mainHandler=new Handler();
class ExampleRunnable implements Runnable {
        int seconds;

        public ExampleRunnable(int seconds) {
            this.seconds = seconds;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++) {
 mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        button.setText("50% process completed");
                        }
                    });
```

2.By Using runOnUIThread()  we have to attach runOnUIThread with post it can be easily understood with example

```
class ExampleRunnable implements Runnable {
        int seconds;



 public ExampleRunnable(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {runOnUIThread.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        button.setText(" Runnable");
                    }
                });
            }
```

3.By using any View we can call by any view here i have called with switch

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private Switch aSwitch;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 aSwitch=findViewById(R.id.switch1);
class ExampleRunnable implements Runnable {
            int seconds;



     public ExampleRunnable(int seconds) {
            this.seconds = seconds;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() { aSwitch.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            button.setText(" Runnable");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

4.By making Handler in another Thread  we have to define Looper because by default it attach us to our thread looper

```
Handler threadHandler=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
threadHandler.post(new Runnable()
{
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                button.setText(" Runnable");
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

This are 4 ways of implementing so I think from it you may now something about runnable thread and runOnUIThread() and Handler is written by other person beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the point of Runnable if one can write the background code in
>   the Thread's run method?

`Runnable` is an interface which used for creating a new thread class similar to the thread class created by extending `java.lang.Thread` class. Only difference is, `Runnable` interface allows the class to extend other class (if required) to override/inherit functionality of some class. Extending `java.lang.Thread` class will revoke this capability.

Also, Runnable interface represent a Task which can be executed by either plain Thread or Executors or any other means. so logical separation of Task as Runnable than Thread is good design decision.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/difference-thread-vs-runnable-interface.html#ixzz2qgjDYJhT