# Run an if-statement for a certain amount of time

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-handler

I want to check if an `int` value is higher than 20 for a certain amount of 15 minutes, if that `int` value stays higher than 20 in those 15 minutes, code will executed

I didn't understand the difference between a `Handler` and a `Runnable`, how to use them, What do they do...

**My question is:**

How can I run an `if statement` for a certain time using a Runnable/Handler

This is the if statement which I want to be checked for 15 mins,

```
if(Speed > 20){
           // Code that will run after 15 mins IF the speed is higher than 20 for all that time
}
```

Comment: use a `while` loop and use `Thread.sleep(2000)` inside it for waiting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the different between Handler, Runnable, and Threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194762/what-is-the-different-between-handler-runnable-and-threads)

Comment: you want to execute your if statement for some time . e.g 5 mins or something else? please explain briefly

Comment: I edited the question @AshishSingh

Comment: Can you show us your code which will give us more insight of your issue

Comment: Perhaps use an observer to listen for changes in the value.  Whenever the value > 20 schedule a task for 20 minutes from now. If the value drops <= 20 then cancel the scheduled task.

Comment: @AndrewS +1 You solved it, Thank you (although i got banned for my question), but still it was answered

Comment: Re, "I didn't understand...a Runnable...what [it does]." If you want to know what a `Runnable` object's `run()` method does, then you should ask the person who wrote it. Normally, that would be _you_. It's not what the `Runnable` does that's interesting:  What's interesting usually is what _somebody else's_ code does with the `Runnable` object that you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code. It uses a while loop which will keep of looping for-ever until two condition are met

1) `i` becomes greater than 20

2) `flag` is set to false

For each iteration, it will sleep for 1 minute

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean flag = true;
    try {
        while (i < 20 && flag) {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
            // Expecting some logic to increment the value of i

            // Or change the flag value of this to exit the while loop
        }
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this, this timer will execute after 1 sec you can add your time you want and put your if statement inside run function

```
  private Timer myTimer;
  myTimer = new Timer();
   myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TimerMethod();
    }

    }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: after certain time you can cancel your timer than it will not call the timer function

Comment: Between runs the variable may momentarily change to <= 20 then immediately change again to > 20.